# How do I know what variables are available for a theme function?

Tags: 7, theming, hooks, debugging

I am using the Menu block module. In one template I have used `kpr($page);` to see what hooks the menu block is calling. I then created the correct function in my theme's template.php file `mytheme_menu_block_wrapper__1()`. The examples I have read suggest that this should not take any arguments.

So what I'm really interested in learning is how to debug drupal.

Is there a function that I can call that will show me all the available variables, something like `drupal_special_dump()` that would show all variables I can use?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel), and it's fantastic [`dpm()`](http://api.lullabot.com/dpm) function, is the most widely used debug method for Drupal (at least I'm pretty sure it is).

It can be used on any variable, including arrays and objects, and will post a message to the standard message area containing a nicely structured representation of the variable. It looks something like this:

[image: Devel Output]

You would use it as simply as:

```
function mytheme_menu_block_wrapper__1($vars) {
  dpm($vars);
}
```

FYI I think all theme functions in Drupal 7 will receive at least one argument which will contain the data for that theme function. That argument is represented by `$vars` in the above example.

If you're looking to get hold of a list of variables that have been defined for the whole page request you might want to look at the PHP [`get_defined_vars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php) function instead.

Answer (score 1):

For theme hooks, the variables that are available will be passed to the hook, usually named $variables. :-)

But here's a big list of all the theme hooks: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme/7